# HTACCESS: 404 error on folder but allow one file

Tags: .htaccess

**My structure**:

```
- root
   - dashboard.php
   - css
      - test.css
      - minified
         - min.css
```

**My htaccess**:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
   deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files /css/minified/min.css>
   allow from all
</Files>
```

How to throw 404 error if anyone who enters the css folder or anywhere inside the folder for example:

```
http://localhost:1993/css
http://localhost:1993/css/test.css
```

but how to allow only one specific file **min.css** inside this folder from root htaccess?

**UPDATED**:

```
RewriteRule ^css/ - [R=404,L]
```

This throw 404 error everywhere in **CSS** folder, but how to exclude **min.css** in this folder from this rule?

**PROBLEM SOLVED**:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files min.css>
   Allow from all
   Satisfy any
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you some reference for .htaccess tricks :

> http://doc.nyubicrew.us/2013/08/trick-of-htaccess.html

you can add this in your .htaccess :

```html
<files secretfile.jpg>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did not find how to enable the file in the forbidden folder and how to throw the 404 error together. I'm a beginner htaccess, I do not know much about it. Could you please help me?

Comment: You can add .htaccess in css folder sir.

Comment: Yes but how can I do it from root htaccess? BTW i updated my question.

Comment: I was edit my post, you can add the code in root htaccess.. how many css do you have ? enter the code each css will fix the problem...

Comment: I have only 1 file (minified and combined from more CSS files). Your code does not work. I still get the forbidden (i request 404 not found) ) including the file.

Comment: if you only have 1 file, why not try to give blank index.php in folder css ?

Comment: in css folder I have several, but in css/minified folder I only have 1 (minified and created by all files from css folder) that I want to use on the web. I want the whole folder 404 not found except for this single file. I really use Options -Indexes in htaccess

Comment: Problem solved! I updated my question. Ty for helping. You kicked me in the right direction.

Comment: I have updated the question, look up - SOLVED PROBLEM code